# Implement Strongly connected Components for Integers in file

Tags: python, algorithm, graph, tree

I am working on implementing the Strongly Connected Components Program from input file of numbers.I know the algorithm on how to do this,but having hard time implementing it in python.

STRONGLY-CONNECTED-COMPONENTS(G)
1. run DFS on G to compute finish times
2. compute G'
3. run DFS on G', but when selecting which node to vist do so
   in order of decreasing finish times (as computed in step 1)
4. output the vertices of each tree in the depth-first forest 
   of step 3 as a separate strongly connected component

The file looks like this:

```
5 5
1 2
2 4
2 3
3 4
4 5
```

The first line is no. of nodes and edges.The rest of the lines are two integers u and v separated by a space, which means a directed edge from node u to node v.The output is to be a strongly connected component and the no.of these components.

```
DFS(G)
1 for each vertex u in G.V
2     u.color = WHITE
3     u.π = NIL
4 time = 0
5 for each vertex u in G.V
6     if u.color == WHITE
7         DFS-VISIT(G, u)

DFS-VISIT(G, u)
1 time = time + 1 // white vertex u has just been discovered
2 u.d = time
3 u.color = GRAY
4 for each v in G.adj[u]
5     if v.color == WHITE
6         v.π = u
7         DFS-VISIT(G, u)
8 u.color = BLACK // blacken u; it is finished
9 time = time + 1
10 u.f = time
```

In the above algorithm how should I traverse the reverse graph to find SCC.

Answer (score 0):

Here, implemented in Python.

Please notice that I construct G and G' at the same time. My DFS is also modified. The `visited` array stores in which component each node is. Also, the DFS receives a `sequence` argument, that is the order in which the nodes will be tested. In the first DFS, we pass a xrange(n), but in the second time, we pass the reversed(order) from the first execution.

The program will output something like:

```
3
[1, 1, 1, 2, 3]
```

In that output, we have 3 strongly connected components, with the 3 first nodes in a single component and the remaining two with one component each.

```
def DFSvisit(G, v, visited, order, component):
    visited[v] = component
    for w in G[v]:
        if not visited[w]:
            DFSvisit(G, w, visited, order, component)
    order.append(v);

def DFS(G, sequence, visited, order):
    components = 0
    for v in sequence:
        if not visited[v]:
            components += 1
            DFSvisit(G, v, visited, order, components)

n, m = (int(i) for i in raw_input().strip().split())

G = [[] for i in xrange(n)]
Gt = [[] for i in xrange(n)]
for i in xrange(m):
    a, b = (int(i) for i in raw_input().strip().split())
    G[a-1].append(b-1)
    Gt[b-1].append(a-1)

order = []
components = [0]*n

DFS(G, xrange(n), [0]*n, order)
DFS(Gt, reversed(order), components, [])

print max(components)
print components
```

Comment: Can you please explain the code if possible and how did you take the input from file.Did you use this -      for line in open(filename):

Comment: I'm assuming you are reading from stdin, like it's done in most contests. You don't have to open the file, just use `python source.py < input.txt`

Comment: Okay.I understood the recursive functions which you have defined,but not after that.

Comment: I wrote assuming you know how a DFS works (since your question is about SCC, not DFS).

Answer (score -1):

```
class graphSCC:
    def __init__(self, graplist):
        self.graphlist = graphlist
        self.visitedNode = {}
        self.SCC_dict = {}      
        self.reversegraph = {}

def reversegraph(self):
    for edge in self.graphlist:
        line = edge.split("\t")
        self.reverseGraph.setdefault(strip("\r"), []).append()
    return self.reverseGraph

def dfs(self):
    SCC_count = 0
    for x in self.reversegraph.keys():
        self.visitednode[x] = 0

    for x in self.reversegraph.keys():
        if self.visitednode[x] == 0:
            count += 1
            self.explore(x, count)

def explore(self, node, count):
    self.visitednode[node] = 1

    for val in self.reversegraph[node]:
        if self.visitednode[val] == 0:
            self.explore(val, count)
    self.SCC_dict.setdefault(count, []).append(node)

length = 0
node = 0
for x in graph.SCC_dict.keys():
    if length < len(graph.SCC_dict[x]):
        length = len(graph.SCC_dict[x])
        node = x
```

length is the required answer